# Ansible group_vars not automatically loaded

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm running `ansible 2.6.4` on `python 2.7.5`. This is my directory structure:

```
inventory/all
group_vars/all.yml
group_vars/lab.yml
playbook.yml
...
```

This is my `inventory/all`:

```
[lab]
localhost
```

`all.yml` contains a bunch of defaults, `lab.yml` has a few overrides. In particular, a repo URL is different. When I run the playbook with `ansible-playbook -i /workspace/inventory/all -c local --diff -v /workspace/local.yml`, the vars in `group_vars/lab.yml` are never loaded. Note that I'm running the command from somewhere other than `/workspace`. If I add `-e @group_vars/lab.yml`, the vars are loaded the playbook runs as it should.

I wouldn't normally care that much, and simply run commands with `-e @group_vars/lab.yml`, except that I'm attempting to get these playbooks running in AWX, which presents the same vars-not-loading behavour.

**edit**

came back to this with fresh eyes. playbook had `vars_files: [group_vars/all.yml]` in it. removed that and all was right with the world.

Comment: Have you already tried placing the `group_vars` inside the `inventory` directory? That's the setup that I have the most experience using. Also, I think you mean `-e @group_vars/lab.yml`, right, not `-i`?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I have tried moving group_vars into the inventory directory, but it yields the same results. Also thanks for the `i` vs `e` headsup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBKAC. playbook had vars_files: [group_vars/all.yml] in it. removed that and all was right with the world.